# Delete key not working in terminal

Tags: command-line

Pressing the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key in the terminal does not delete forwards. It **does** work in editors and the browser, only the terminal appears to have this problem. <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> still works as a delete key.

I've run these as per another post:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep -i delete
keycode  91 = KP_Delete KP_Decimal KP_Delete KP_Decimal
keycode 119 = Delete NoSymbol Delete
$ sudo dumpkeys | grep -i remove
keycode 111 = Remove
string Remove = "\033[3~"
```

I'm not sure what this implies.

Where can I go from here?

Using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and the default terminal

Comment: You can test your KEY_DELETE with [`xev`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xev.1.html), [`evtest`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/evtest.1.html), [`xinput --test deviceID`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/xinput.1.html#options) or [`libinput debug-events`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/libinput.1.html).

Comment: you did those steps from another post after the problem or before the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following details in this FAQ https://git.suckless.org/st/file/FAQ.html#l25 I copied inputrc `cp /etc/inputrc ~/.inputrc` and uncomment `set enable-keypad on` there.

Extract from the link

```
  ## Why doesn't the Del key work in some programs?

  Taken from the terminfo manpage:

    If the terminal has a keypad that transmits codes when the keys
    are pressed, this information can be given. Note that it is not
    possible to handle terminals where the keypad only works in
    local (this applies, for example, to the unshifted HP 2621 keys).
    If the keypad can be set to transmit or not transmit, give these
    codes as smkx and rmkx. Otherwise the keypad is assumed to
    always transmit.

  In the st case smkx=E[?1hE= and rmkx=E[?1lE>, so it is mandatory that
  applications which want to test against keypad keys send these
  sequences.

  But buggy applications (like bash and irssi, for example) don't do this. A fast
  solution for them is to use the following command:

    $ printf '\033[?1h\033=' >/dev/tty

  or
    $ tput smkx

  In the case of bash, readline is used. Readline has a different note in its
  manpage about this issue:

    enable-keypad (Off)
        When set to On, readline will try to enable the
        application keypad when it is called. Some systems
        need this to enable arrow keys.

  Adding this option to your .inputrc will fix the keypad problem for all
  applications using readline.
```